# Numpy arctan2 of multidimensional array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, multidimensional-array

I am trying to shape up some code that was written to take single `float` values, so it works fine using 1D (and eventually 2D) `numpy.arrays` as input.

Striped down to a minimal example the function looks like this (no this example is not doing anything useful, but if `do_math` and `do_some_more_math` are removed, it will produce exactly the described behavior):

```
def do_complicated_math(r, g, b):
    rgb = numpy.array([r, g, b])

    # Math! No change in array shape. To run example just comment out.
    rgb = do_math(rgb)

    m_2 = numpy.array([[rgb[0], 0, 0], [0, rgb[1], 0], [0, 0, rgb[2]]])

    # Get additional matrices needed for transformation.
    # These are actually predefined 3x3 float arrays
    m_1 = numpy.ones((3, 3))
    m_3 = numpy.ones((3, 3))

    # Transform the rgb array
    rgb_transformed = m_1.dot(m_2).dot(m_3).dot(rgb)

    # More math! No change in array shape. To run example just comment out.
    rgb_transformed = do_some_more_math(rgb_transformed)

    # Almost done just one more thing...
    return numpy.arctan2(rgb_transformed, rgb_transformed)

# Works fine
do_complicated_math(1, 1, 1)

# Fails
x = numpy.ones(6)
do_complicated_math(x, x, x)
```

This function works fine as long, as as `r`, `g` and `b` are individual numbers, however, if they are given as `numpy.array` (e.g., in order to transform multiple rgb values at once) the `numpy.arctan2` throws the following exception:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  (...) line 32, in do_complicated_math
    numpy.arctan2(rgb_transformed, rgb_transformed)
AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'arctan2'
```

I haven't found any definitive answer as to what this is trying to tell me. `arctan2` seems to work fine is used with multidimensional arrays like this:

```
numpy.arctan2(numpy.ones((3,4,5)), numpy.ones((3,4,5)))
```

So I assume the problem has to be somewhere in how `m_2` is created, or how the multiplications of `m_1`, `m_2`, `m_3` and `rgb` get propagated, but I can't seem to figure out just where it breaks.

Comment: Are you sure you haven't assigned an array to the name `numpy` accidentally? Try `type(numpy)` somewhere. Could you provide a [minimal example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that others can actually run, and ensure that it recreates the issue you're seeing?

Comment: The above code is a complete minimal example. Just remove the math calls and it will produce exactly the described behavior.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that `rgb_transformed` is no longer a standard numpy array when you pass it to `arctan2`, it has become an object array:

```
print rgb_transformed
"""[[array([ 9.,  9.,  9.,  9.,  9.,  9.])
  array([ 9.,  9.,  9.,  9.,  9.,  9.])
  array([ 9.,  9.,  9.,  9.,  9.,  9.])
  array([ 9.,  9.,  9.,  9.,  9.,  9.])
  array([ 9.,  9.,  9.,  9.,  9.,  9.])
  array([ 9.,  9.,  9.,  9.,  9.,  9.])]
 [array([ 9.,  9.,  9.,  9.,  9.,  9.])
  array([ 9.,  9.,  9.,  9.,  9.,  9.])
  array([ 9.,  9.,  9.,  9.,  9.,  9.])
  array([ 9.,  9.,  9.,  9.,  9.,  9.])
  array([ 9.,  9.,  9.,  9.,  9.,  9.])
  array([ 9.,  9.,  9.,  9.,  9.,  9.])]
 [array([ 9.,  9.,  9.,  9.,  9.,  9.])
  array([ 9.,  9.,  9.,  9.,  9.,  9.])
  array([ 9.,  9.,  9.,  9.,  9.,  9.])
  array([ 9.,  9.,  9.,  9.,  9.,  9.])
  array([ 9.,  9.,  9.,  9.,  9.,  9.])
  array([ 9.,  9.,  9.,  9.,  9.,  9.])]]"""
print rgb_transformed.shape
#(3, 6)
print rgb_transformed.dtype
#object
```

So the problem it simpler than I thought:

This line:

```
m_2 = numpy.array([[rgb[0], 0, 0], [0, rgb[1], 0], [0, 0, rgb[2]]])
print m_2
#array([[array([ 1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.]), 0, 0],
#       [0, array([ 1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.]), 0],
#       [0, 0, array([ 1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.])]], dtype=object)
```

Here object arrays are created, propagating through the rest of the code.

**EDIT**

To get around this issue you likely need to broadcast your arrays slightly differently. Basically change the outer dimension to reflect the changing `rgb` values. *Disclaimer:* I don't have a good way to verify the result of this in the context of your question, so treat the output with due care.

```
import numpy as np

def do_complicated_math(r, g, b):
    rgb = np.array([r, g, b])

    # create a transposed version of the m_2 array
    m_2 = np.zeros((r.size,3,3))
    for ii,ar in enumerate(rgb):
        m_2[:,ii][:,ii][:] = ar
    m_1 = np.ones((3, 3))
    m_3 = np.ones((3, 3))

    rgb_transformed = m_1.dot(m_2).dot(m_3).dot(rgb)

    print rgb_transformed
    return np.arctan2(rgb_transformed, rgb_transformed)

x = np.ones(6)
do_complicated_math(x, x, x)                                                                                                                        

r = np.array([0.2,0.3,0.1])
g = np.array([1.0,1.0,0.2])
b = np.array([0.3,0.3,0.3])
do_complicated_math(r, g, b)
```

This will work for arrays as input only, but adding handling for single values as input should be trivial.

Comment: Great! So How can I avoid this happening?

Comment: We'll that depends on what you want to get back from transform. Do you want the results as if you had iterated through the various rgb combinations?

Comment: So I have added a potential fix, that will work with array input. You will need to verify it independently. If it works, i'll remove the disclaimer.

Comment: Unfortunately this didn't work out for me. I ended up doing something close to iterating over the rgb values after all. Not ideal but it works. Thanks for your help!